# Using other base systems in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, radix

How do I use another base system in SymPy? I would like to do something similar to `Rational(string)` but not in base 10.

Comment: I don't know much about SymPy, but rational numbers are rational regardless of what base you're using to represent them. Is it just the parsing of the other base you need or do you definitely need the result to be a `Rational` object? Can you give an example of the sort of string you need to convert?

Comment: @Blckknght For example, I might want to take the string 1.1 and turn it into 4/3 using base 3.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your terminology. Is your string "1.1" already in base 3? Then it would correspond to 4/3 in base 10 which is equal to 11/10 in base 3. Or is your string in base 10 and you want to convert to base 3? 1.1 in base 10 is 1.002200220022... in base 3 which is 102/101 in base 3.

Comment: @Hannebambel The string represents base 3; that is, like you said in your former interpretation, `1.1` in base 3 becomes `4/3` or `11/10` in base 3. My question becomes how to get a `Rational` object from this.

Comment: I've found no way doing it in sympy directly. Maybe you can construct something on top of sympy's functionality for polynomials over finite fields? http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/wester.html#advanced-factoring-over-finite-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you need is available in Python:

```
def sdigits(s, b, tuple=False):
    p = len(s.split('.')[1])
    n, d = (int(s.replace('.', ''), base=b), b**p)
    if tuple:
        return n, d
    return '%s/%s' % (n, d)
```

This produces for the following,

```
sdigits('1.1', 3) -> '4/3'
sdigits('1.01', 3) -> '10/9'
sdigits('-1.12', 3) -> '-14/9'
sdigits('-1.12', 3, tuple=True) -> (-14, 9)
sdigits('1.2', 4) -> '6/4'
```

To benefit from SymPy's ability to provide simplified ratios, you can pass either output to Rational:

```
Rational(sdigits('1.2', 4)) -> 3/2
Rational(*sdigits('1.2', 4, tuple=True)) -> 3/2
```